# ImportError: No module named 'httplib'

Tags: selenium2, python

I have recently updated selenium Webdriver to 2.38.1 and I am writing scripts using python.
When I run the test case I have I get the following error

*Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:/Users/xrankum/PycharmProjects/Automation Practice/Create Prepaid Data Susbcription.py", line 4, in <module>

from selenium import  webdriver

File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox

File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 26, in <module>
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.extension_connection import ExtensionConnection
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\extension_connection.py", line 22, in <module>
from selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection import RemoteConnection
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 21, in <module>

import httplib

ImportError: No module named 'httplib'*
```

My tests were running perfectly until I updated to the new version of selenium.

Can anyone help me how to resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it is supported.

I had the same error using python3, selenium 2.38.1, and ubuntu 13.10.  Here is how I fixed it.

While investigating selenium suddenly not working after I upgraded it, I noticed that calling

```
pip3 list
```

showed an error as well.  You can see a similar error as to what I had here: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1093

So I uninstalled selenium

```
sudo pip3 uninstall selenium
```

Ran

```
sudo pip3 install -U distribute
```

Confirmed that pip3 list worked.

Installed selenium again

```
sudo pip3 install selenium
```

Now my test works. Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried the above steps and it still isn't working for me. Any thoughts?

Comment: @ChandrasekarSreenivas You're getting an identical error as Ranadheer and Issac?

Answer (score 0):

When looking at your post I noticed you are using Python 3.3. I'm not sure httplib is supported in 3.3.

[On this 2.7 standard library page](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/internet.html), httplib can be found.

[On this 3.3 standard library page](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/internet.html), httplib cannot be found:

Have you tried calling the same script from a Python 2.7 installation and received the same error?

Comment: Well, the tests were working perfectly for Python3 before updating selenium.